# laravel - phpunit - mock network calls

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

I have a Laravel (5.4) app that I am unit/feature testing. I am relatively new to unit testing.

The procedure I am testing makes a network call (using Guzzle), and I perform some actions on the result.

What would be the suggested way of mocking the network call, and returning a predefined response?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Testing Guzzle inside of Laravel Controller with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162281/unit-testing-guzzle-inside-of-laravel-controller-with-phpunit)