# How do I mock a GuzzleHttp client that makes a request to a third-party API in a Laravel feature test?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

In a Laravel project (Laravel 8 on PHP 8.0) I have a feature test in which I test an internal endpoint. The endpoint has a Controller calls a method on a Service. The Service then tries to call a third-party endpoint. It is this third-party endpoint that I would like to mock. The situation currently looks like this:

#### Internal Endpoint Feature Test

```php
public function testStoreInternalEndpointSuccessful(): void
{
    // arrange, params & headers are not important in this problem
    $params = [];
    $headers = [];

    // act
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/v1/internal-endpoint', $params, $headers);

    // assert
    $response->assertResponseStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

#### Internal Endpoint Controller

```php
class InternalEndpointController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(protected InternalService $internalService)
    {
    }

    public function store(Request $request): InternalResource
    {
        $data = $this.internalService->fetchExternalData();

        return new InternalResource($data); // etc.
    }
}
```

#### Internal Service

```php
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;

class InternalService
{
    public function __construct(protected ClientInterface $client)
    {
    }
    
    public function fetchExternalData()
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', 'v1/external-data');
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

        return $body;
    }
}
```

I have looked at Guzzle's documentation, but it [seems like](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler) the `MockHandler` strategy requires you to execute the http request inside of the test, which is not wat I want in my test. I want Guzzle's http client to be mocked and to return a custom http response that I can specify in my test. I have tried to mock Guzzle's http client like this:

```php
public function testStoreInternalEndpointSuccessful(): void
{
    // arrange, params & headers are not important in this problem
    $params = [];
    $headers = [];

    $mock = new MockHandler([
        new GuzzleResponse(200, [], $contactResponse),
    ]);

    $handlerStack = HandlerStack::create($mock);
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $handlerStack]);

    $mock = Mockery::mock(Client::class);
    $mock
        ->shouldReceive('create')
        ->andReturn($client);

    // act
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/v1/internal-endpoint', $params, $headers);

    // assert
    $response->assertResponseStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

But the `InternalService` does not seem to hit this mock in the test.

I have also considered and tried to use [Http Fake](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#faking-responses), but it didn't work and I assume Guzzle's http client does not extend Laravel's http client.

What would be the best way to approach this problem and mock the third-party endpoint?

### Edit

Inspired by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162281/unit-testing-guzzle-inside-of-laravel-controller-with-phpunit), I [have managed to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774432/4496102) by injecting a Guzzle client with mocked responses into my service. The difference to the aforementioned StackOverflow question is that I had to use `$this->app->singleton` instead of `$this->app->bind` because my DI was configured differently:

#### AppServiceProvider.php

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Service\InternalService;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        // my app uses ->singleton instead of ->bind
        $this->app->singleton(InternalService::class, function () {
            return new InternalService(new Client([
                'base_uri' => config('app.internal.base_url'),
            ]));
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why overcomplicate stuff? Depending on which Laravel version you are using (you did not share which one, it is very important next time you do so), you can directly fake HTTP responses: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning the version, I have added it to the post. I have tried to use `Http Fake`, but when the service still received the response from the "internet" instead of the response I configured in Http fake. The link to the documentation that you provided (documentation is similar for Laravel 8) mentions Laravel's HTTP Client, so I assumed Http fake only works for that specific http client and not for Guzzly's http client. Can you perhaps confirm/reject this perhaps? If not, the 6-7 extra lines as specified in my own answer (see below) do not seem an overcomplication to me.

Comment: Correct, you must use `Http` Facade for this `Http::fake` to work. It is using `Guzzle` behind scenes, but the Facade is the one doing the magic! Next time, If you are able, use or refactor to use `Http` Facade, it will help you A LOT, specially with tests :D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your depending injection, you want to `bind` or `singleton`-ify your `InternalService` with a custom Guzzle http client that returns mocked responses, e.g. like this:

```php
public function testStoreInternalEndpointSuccessful(): void
{

    // depending on your DI configuration,
    // this could be ->bind or ->singleton
    $this->app->singleton(InternalService::class, function($app) {
        $mockResponse = json_encode([
            'data' => [
                'id' => 0,
                'name' => 'Jane Doe',
                'type' => 'External',
                'description' => 'Etc. you know the drill',
            ]
        ]);

        $mock = new GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler([
            new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response(200, [], $mockResponse),
        ]);

        $handlerStack = GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($mock);
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $handlerStack]);

        return new InternalService($client);
    });

    // arrange, params & headers are not important in this problem
    $params = [];
    $headers = [];

    // act
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/v1/internal-endpoint', $params, $headers);

    // assert
    $response->assertResponseStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

See also: [Unit Testing Guzzle inside of Laravel Controller with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33162281/4496102)

Comment: The only think that I don’t like of this approach is to define the exact sequence of responses, knowing that the order of requests in a service could change. This apart, I agree with you.